# Gatsby plugin for third-party APIs throw error

Tags: graphql, gatsby

My scripts are set up like:

```
"start-dev": "npm-run-all -p client server db",
"client": "gatsby develop",
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"db": "json-server db.json"
```

So for development I have a mock database served by json-server and an endpoint served by json-server. So I installed the plugin as per the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/third-party-graphql/). And configured the plugin like:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-graphql`,
  options: {
    typeName: `racing`,
    fieldName: 'members',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/members',
  },
},
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-graphql`,
  options: {
    typeName: `racing`,
    fieldName: 'teams',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/teams',
  },
},
```

When I run `yarn run start-dev` I get an error:

```
"gatsby-source-graphql" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:
Response not successful: Received status code 404
  ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 404
```

plus there is some stack trace information. Eventual I get the usual links to go to GraphQL (https:localhost:8000/__graphql), but I don't see the API fieldName in available queries in this tool. So the overall question is how should I setup to query a "third-party" API? Specifically, is this an expected error? How do I query the API using the GraphQL tool?

Thank you.

Comment: This error occurs when you write wrong graphql query, can you please add these query!

Comment: You can configure the fetch implementation used by `gatsby-source-graphql`. You can use this to print which requests it makes. Since it's a 404, presumably the requests are going to the wrong address.
See https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/24603#issuecomment-636000987

Comment: @BloodyLogic The error comes from the configuration. No query has been attempted at the time of the startup when the error occurs.

Comment: @ehrencrona Thank you for the tip for the "fetch" option. Would you mind pointing me to documentation on this option so I know what it does and maybe help me diagnose the problem?

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-graphql/ here the docs!

Comment: @ehrencrona I tried adding a fetch option and I get
"gatsby-source-graphql" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:

fetch is not defined
How do I get fetch defined? And I did see the documentation for this plug-in. Thank you.

Comment: Is `http://localhost:3000/api/teams` a graphql api or a rest api?

Answer (score 0):

As the message suggests you are having an HTTP error. It is not a graphql error, it is probably something with your plugin or server configuration (missing auth headers, wrong endpoint, incompatible GraphQL server, etc).

try the same queries manually against your remote endpoint with the same configuration as the plugin has using `curl` or `postman`!

To provide the `auth header` Gatsby use to two of environmental variables `.env.development` and `.env.production` in your `/` root directory, prefixed with `GATSBY_` will become available in browser JavaScript:

```
GATSBY_API_URL=https://dev.example.com/api
```

[Resource](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/)

Comment: I have changed some things. But only the port. Now I get an error:
```

"gatsby-source-graphql" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:

Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0


 ServerParseError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

```

Comment: I have created a branch for Gatsby. Under  `https://github.com/KevinBurton/GreatState/tree/gatsby` . I have made some changes but the error although different seems to be still with the testing library. Just run `yarn test` and you will see the error, .

Comment: I don't see a 404?

Comment: @KevinBurton I think this is private repo you created it's why I'm not able to see! try to open the URL in incognito!

Comment: So it is with the GitHub repo that the 404 comes from now the app. I will look at it. Thank you.